# A fallacious argument concerning certain topological groups

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, algebraic-number-theory, topological-groups

Let $K$ be a non-Archimedean local field, and let $\mathcal{O}$ be its ring of integers. Let $U$ be the group of $4 \times 4$ unipotent upper-triangular matrices over $K$. Consider the topology on $K$ induced by its normalized absolute value, and identify $U$ with the product space $K^6$ e.g. by the map

$$
 \begin{pmatrix}
1 & u_{12} & u_{13} & u_{14} \\
 & 1 & u_{23} & u_{24}\\
& & 1 & u_{34}  \\
 & & & 1
\end{pmatrix} \mapsto (u_{12},u_{13},u_{14},u_{23},u_{24},u_{34})$$

Then $U$ is a locally profinite group with respect to the topology induced by $K^6$. Now, fix $a \in K$ with $a \neq 0$. Since $\mathcal{O}$ is compact and open in $K$, the set

$$
N:=\left\{ \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & a\alpha & 0 \\
  & 1 & \alpha & 0 \\
  & & 1 & 0 \\
  & & & 1
\end{pmatrix} : \alpha \in \mathcal{O} \right\}
$$
is a compact open subgroup of $U$. On the other hand, the subgroup

$$
L:= \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & * \\
  & 1 & * & * \\
  & & 1 & * \\
  & & & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

is closed in $U$, so that $L \cap N$ is a compact open subgroup of $L$. But
$ L \cap N =\{I_4\}$, which implies that $L$ is discrete. In particular, the "root" subgroup

$$X:= \left\{ \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  & 1 & \alpha & 0 \\
  & & 1 & 0 \\
  & & & 1 \end{pmatrix} : \alpha \in \mathcal{O} \right\}$$
is contained in $L$, and so it is also discrete with respect to the subspace topology. As $X$ is homeomorphic to $\mathcal{O}$ and $\mathcal{O}$ is compact, this implies that $\mathcal{O}$ must be finite. But this is absurd (e.g. take the field $K=\mathbf{Q}_p$ of $p-$adic numbers, whose ring of integers $\mathcal{O}$ is the ring $\mathbf{Z}_p$ of $p-$adic integers).

I stumbled upon this by accident, and I'm desperately struggling with finding the error.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: $N$ is essentially $\{0\} \times (a,1)\cdot \mathcal{O} \times \{0\}^3$, which is only open in $K^6$ if $K$ is discrete.

Comment: Daniel Fischer's comment positively closes this question.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry maybe I misunderstood your notations, but what is your I_4 ? the identity matrix ? If so you don’t get `$L\intersect N = I_4$`

Comment: Yes, $I_4$ denotes the $4 \times 4$ identity matrix. But the intersection is indeed trivial: let $(u_{ij})$ be an element in $N$, with $u_{23}=a \alpha$ for some $\alpha \in \mathcal{O}$; if $(u_{ij})$ also belongs to $L$, then $u_{23}=0$ i.e. $a \alpha = 0$, and so $\alpha=0$ since $a \neq 0$ by hypothesis and $K$ has no zero divisors.

Comment: But what the \ast in L really means ? It should mean that anything is allowed, right ? So I guess I misunderstood your notations...

Comment: Yes, "$\ast$" means arbitrary entries in $K$. On the other hand, in the previous comment I meant to say $u_{13}=a \alpha$, not $u_{23}=a \alpha$. If this doesn't make it clear, I can again explain the argument: Let $u \in L \cap N$. We show that $u=I_4$ necessarily. Now, since $u \in L$, we have $u_{12}=u_{13}=0$. Since $u \in N$, we have $u_{14}=u_{24}=u_{34}=0$, and $u_{13}=a \alpha, u_{23}=\alpha$ for some $\alpha \in \mathcal{O}$. But $u_{13}=0$, so $a \alpha=0$ which implies $\alpha=0$ because $a \neq 0$ by hypothesis and $K$ has no zero divisors. Thus $u_{23}=0$, and so $u=I_4$.

Comment: Sorry I think it is clear to me now. It is quite silly I didn’t notice the entry at (13) is related to that at (23). But zero divisor is not a problem here as K is a field. Thanks !